# Firebird select distinct with count

Tags: sql, firebird

In Firebird 2.5 I have a table of hardware device events; each row contains a timestamp, a device ID and an integer status of the event.  I need to retrieve a rowset of the subset of IDs with non-0 statuses and the number of instances of the non-0 events for each ID, within a specified date range.  I can get the subset of IDs with non-0 statuses in the specified date range, but I can't figure out how to get the count of non-0-status rows associated with each ID in the same rowset.  I'd prefer to do this in a query rather than a stored proc, if possible.

The table is:

```
RPR_HISTORY
    TSTAMP    timestamp
    RPRID     integer
    PARID     integer
    LASTRES   integer
    LASTCUR   float
```

The rowset I want is like

```
RPRID    ERRORCOUNT
-------------------
18       4
19       2
66       7
```

The query

```sql
select distinct RPRID from RPR_HISTORY
where (LASTRES <> 0)
  and (TSTAMP >= :STARTSTAMP);
```

gives me the IDs I'm looking for, but obviously not the count of non-0-status rows for each ID.  I've tried a bunch of combinations of nested queries derived from the above; all generate errors, usually on grouping or aggregation errors.  It seems like a straightforward thing to do but is just escaping me.

Comment: This post is missing debugging details, including input tables, output table, your best coding attempt and how it differs from your expected output. Please update your post accordingly.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: You probably want `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1):

Got it!  The query

```
select rh.RPRID, count(rh.RPRID) from RPR_HISTORY rh 
where (rh.LASTRES <> 0)
  and (rh.TSTAMP >= :STARTSTAMP)
  and rh.RPRID in
(select distinct rd.RPRID from RPR_HISTORY rd where rd.LASTRES <> 0) 
group by rh.RPRID;
```

returns the rowset I need.

Comment: Can't you remove `and rh.RPRID in (select distinct rd.RPRID from RPR_HISTORY rd where rd.LASTRES <> 0)`? That condition will always be true since you already have `rh.LASTRES <> 0`.

Comment: Actually, yes, that works too.